# Need help Grouping and creating a select statement in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables with these structures:

[image]

And the result that I am looking for is this:

[image]

I have tried multiple grouping statements but I have not been able to get near to something to the structure I need, if anybody can give me hand.  Thanks

Comment: Please, no screenshots of spreadsheet.

Comment: how do I create a table in stack overflow without taking forever?

Comment: That's your response? Seriously? Why would you expect someone to spend forever answering your question?

Comment: Just pointing out that is super easy with a screenshot of a spreadsheet and I don't know how to do it other way, now if you don't care to explain then please just refrain from commenting, also I don,t see anywhere in the posting section, anything about posting spreadsheet  screeshots, seems like is you that don't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select u.userid, u.name,
       count(distinct case when b.visibility = 1 then b.blogid end) as num_public_blogs,
       count(distinct case when b.visibility = 0 then b.blogid end) as num_private_blogs,
       count(case when b.visibility = 1 then bp.blogid end) as num_public_posts,
       count(case when b.visibility = 0 then bp.blogid end) as num_private_posts
from users u left join
     blogs b
     on b.userid = u.userid left join
     blogposts bp
     on bp.blogid = b.blogid
group by u.userid, u.name;
```